# What is the best option to inform the user to reload uitableview on receiving updates from server on screen through UI xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, xamarin, notifications

I've a UITableview on the controller and if it has 500 records or cells and when iam at 250th or 300th record i got new/updated records in the background from server. How can we inform or best way to inform user about those updates in order to reload the tableview through UI?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the new data and where that data is to be displayed (e.g. updating previous cells or appearing at the bottom of the table), but popping a “toast” message on screen is one option.

Answer (score 0):

- If you wanna send a notification automatically from the server to the user that exist new elements and update the UITableView you can try to use a push notification. This notification works when user also is not seen the app or the have the app is suspended.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/user-notifications/deprecated/remote_notifications_in_ios/

or if you wanna maintain a task reloading the UITableView all the day in different moments of the day.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/

---

exist many solution, depends what you wanna do with the data and the user.